# How do I move my Tiny Death Star from my old iPad to my new iPad?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I bought a new iPad today and restored from my old iPad's iCloud backup, but when I opened up Tiny Death Star on the new iPad it didn't have any of my old data. It was like a proton torpedo had just been shot into my Death Star's exhaust port. :(

I haven't erased my old iPad yet, so I still have the data there. Can I get my Death Star back or have the Rebels won?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Tiny Death Star data is not backed up to either iCloud or iTunes, so there is unfortunately no way to transfer the data. Hopefully, someone will find that I am wrong. :(

**UPDATE: Version 1.2.2 appears to fix the issue.**

I noticed the last update (Version 1.2.2) mentioned fixing "Reset Game Issues". I had kept my old iPad around to see if they fixed it, so I updated Tiny Death Star on my old iPad to Version 1.2.2 and performed another backup. When I restored this new backup to my new iPad, everything copied over successfully! Now witness the power of the fully armed and operational battle station!

Also, there appears to be a new screen in the app to help with resetting issues. Under menu, tap the Settings button at the top (it has a little wrench icon), then hit the "Help" button. This screen will show you a big long number that Disney may be able to use to restore your save file if you have further issues (though I did not need to resort to contacting them after all).

Comment: Richard, perhaps you should consider shooting an email to Disney customer support on the subject to see if they a) will address this in a future update b) can confirm that there is in fact no way to fix this.

Comment: Richard!  Congrats!  I'm glad to hear that worked out for you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The safest bet is to do a complete backup on your old iPad into iTunes.  Next, plug the new one in, and restore the backup onto the new iPad.  WARNING:  This will replace all of the data from your new iPad with that of your old iPad.  But, it should also bring the progress from your TDS with it.

Comment: I tried this just now and it didn't seem to work for me. I backed up the old iPad to iTunes on my Mac this time, and I made sure to tell iTunes to copy my apps to my Mac during the backup. But still when I restored, Tiny Death Star started me off at the beginning. Is this just me? Have you been able to restore on a new device? I'm going to give it another shot though - I did notice that some other apps were not copied anyway, so something might have gone wrong.

Comment: How did you restore?  Did you specifically restore it from the backup?  Because if you did, it should have cloned it. You need to hit the restore button on the middle of the right side of the page in iTunes next to the backup button. Not the ios restore!

Comment: At this point I have tried both the "Restore Backup" button and the "Restore iPad" button, and both have copied the Tiny Death Star app but not its data. I even resolved an issue in which iTunes was not copying all my apps over, which seemed to just be due to my iPad's storage being overly full when I backed up the apps to iTunes. So I have a full restore from iTunes which appears to have the data for all of my apps - except Tiny Death Star! :(

Comment: Last try:  you are sure you are using the correct backup?  Make sure you are not merely restoring the backup of the NEW iPad onto itself.  Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that I haven't ever made a backup of my new iPad, but just to make sure I deleted all my old backups and am making a fresh one and will see how that goes. But I'm really thinking that the developer is just excluding some necessary data from the backup, which they can easily do: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: Richard - good choice. Unfortunately, iTunes can frequently make a backup without you choosing to do so. I've said no to the backup option, and it has done so regardless.  If this doesn't work, I can offer only my regrets and sincerest wishes for a speedy rebuilding.

Comment: I've tried everything, and no luck. I don't feel like starting over, so I think I'm done with this game.

Comment: My deepest and heartfelt condolences.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer though, because it was helpful for trying to fix it, but I can't say that it is the right answer, since it seems the app just doesn't back up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having issue, try this. It worked for me today.

On your old ipad/iphone, make sure that you have connected to Facebook. This has to be done before the backup.

Backup your iphone.

On the new iphone/ipad, restore from the backup you just made.

Log in to tinydeathstar. It will look like it's all new and makes you go through the first tutorial bit. Once you can get to the menu, connect to Facebook. Then select the local version once connect and volia.

Should work. Good luck!